# show $\{ x \times (-x)\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2_l$

Tags: general-topology

When Munkres's book shows *the production of two Lindelöf spaces need not be Lindelöf*, it uses the example of the space $\mathbb{R}_l$ (with low limit topology), that $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$ is not Lindelöf.

It says
$$
L=\{ x \times (-x)  | x \in \mathbb{R}_l \}
$$
is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2_l$, but why?

Comment: It is a closed subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ with respect to the usual topology and thus is closed in the product lower limit topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s easy enough to show directly that $\Bbb R_\ell^2\setminus L$ is open. Let $\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R_\ell^2\setminus L$. If $x+y>0$, then $$L\cap\big([x,x+1)\times[y,y+1)\big)=\varnothing\,.$$ If $x+y<0$, let $r=\frac12\big||x|-|y|\big|$; then $$L\cap\big([x,x+r)\times[y,y+r)\big)=\varnothing\,.$$

Comment: when $r \leq 0$,  $ [x, x+r) $ does not belong to low limit topology.

Comment: @whitegreen: Apparently I inadvertently typed parentheses instead of the intended absolute value. Fixed now.

Comment: thanks! it is can be written $[x, (x-y)/2) \times [y, (y-x)/2) $

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\tau_e \subseteq \tau_l$ where the former is the usual Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$ and the latter the lower limti (Sorgenfrey) topology. So the same relation holds for their resp. squares and the antidiagonal you mentioned is closed in the plane as the graph of the continuous function $x \to -x$, and so closed in $\Bbb R_l^2$ as well.